# SwiftUI on WatchOS - code for launching Activity or Workout App?

Tags: swiftui, watchos, launching-application

I have a SwiftUI app in which I would like to show the "WorkOut" and "Activity" icons and launch those apps when the respective icon is tapped.

Is this possible in WatchOS6 & SwiftUI?

I know this "can I launch another app from within my app" question has been asked before for iOS or WatchOS but the answers seem old and I was hoping that this is now possible in WatchOS 6.

Thanks!

Gerard

Answer (score 0):

`MKMapItem` has a method `openInMaps()` that you can use to open the Maps app.

I don't think there is an equivalent for the Workout/Activity apps.

Also, I seems like using their icons is against the guidelines. You can only use the rings.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/healthkit/overview/